# Merging adjacent bins with same property in GenomicRanges object

Tags: r, bioinformatics, intervals, bioconductor, genomicranges

Having segmented a genome into adjacent non-overlapping bins, e.g. by `tileGenome`, I have computed some property by some means for each bin (say either 1 or 2).

Now I want to merge adjacent with the same property.
An minimal example is illustrated below:

```r
library(GenomicRanges)
chrSizes <- c(chr1 = 1000, chr2 = 500)
bins   <- tileGenome(chrSizes, tilewidth = 200, cut.last.tile.in.chrom = T)
bins$property <- rep(1:2, each = 4)
bins
GRanges object with 8 ranges and 1 metadata column:
      seqnames    ranges strand |  property
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
  [1]     chr1     1-200      * |         1
  [2]     chr1   201-400      * |         1
  [3]     chr1   401-600      * |         1
  [4]     chr1   601-800      * |         1
  [5]     chr1  801-1000      * |         2
  [6]     chr2     1-200      * |         2
  [7]     chr2   201-400      * |         2
  [8]     chr2   401-500      * |         2
  -------
  seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome
```

The first 4 bins have property 1, so should be combined into one bin.

I have looked through the `GRanges` documentation and can't find an obvious native solution.
Note, `seqname` boundaries have to be taken into account (e.g. chr1 and chr2 remain separated irrespective of the property)
Obviously, I one could use a loop, but I'd rather use a native GRange solutions e.g. using `union` which I might have overseen.

The desired output should look something like this:

```r
      seqnames    ranges strand |  property
         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
  [1]     chr1     1-800      * |         1
  [2]     chr1  801-1000      * |         2
  [3]     chr2     1-500      * |         2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R GenomicRanges:

```
result <- unlist(reduce(split(bins, ~property)))
result$property <- names(result)

# GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
# seqnames    ranges strand |    property
# <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
# 1     chr1     1-800      * |           1
# 2     chr1  801-1000      * |           2
# 2     chr2     1-500      * |           2
# -------
# seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome
```

Python PyRanges:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import pyranges as pr

c = """Chromosome Start End Value
chr1 1 200 Python
chr1 201 400 Python
chr1 401 600 Python
chr1 601 800 Python
chr1 801 1000 R
chr2 1 200 R
chr2 201 400 R
chr2 401 500 R"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(c), sep=" ")
gr = pr.PyRanges(df)
gr.merge(by="Value", slack=1)

# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | Value      |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
# | chr1         |         1 |       800 | Python     |
# | chr1         |       801 |      1000 | R          |
# | chr2         |         1 |       500 | R          |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 3 rows and 4 columns from 2 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Maybe, the code can be even a bit streamlined like this: `result <- unlist(reduce(split(bins, ~property)));
result$score <- names(result)`. Feel free to update the answer if you agree.

Comment: Yes, thanks. R is not my main language, so I learnt something new from your comment :)